# why is this not returning the access token from JWT?

Tags: mongodb, jwt, express-jwt

I'm trying to generate a JWT access token to verify the user through the header and avoid that after each page reload the user gets logged out. But whenever I try to try this it doesn't logs the user in.

Here is where I log the user in and create a jwt session:

```
router.route('/login').post((req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local" , {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.status(400).send("No user exists");
    else {
      req.logIn(user, {session: false}, err => {
        if (err) throw error;
          const token = jwt.sign(user, 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMTAwOTUiLCJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJ3cml0ZXIiLCJtb2RlcmF0b3IiXSwiaWF0IjoxNTIzODE3OTk5LCJleHAiOjE1MjQ0MjI3OTl9.rrpyIW0ftJGna1c_SHH6Hus8hBd2-CUqofaSIUHj0C0');
         res.json({user, token});
      })
    }
  })(req, res, next)
})
```

Here is where I set the callback for jwt:

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new localStrategy((username, password, done) => {
      Users.findOne({username: username}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err
        if (!user) return done(null, false);
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if(result === true) {
            return done(null, user)
          } else {
            return done(null, false)
          }
        })
      })
    })
  )

  passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey   : 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMTAwOTUiLCJuYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJ3cml0ZXIiLCJtb2RlcmF0b3IiXSwiaWF0IjoxNTIzODE3OTk5LCJleHAiOjE1MjQ0MjI3OTl9.rrpyIW0ftJGna1c_SHH6Hus8hBd2-CUqofaSIUHj0C0'
    },
    function (jwtPayload, cb) {

        //find the user in db if needed. This functionality may be omitted if you store everything you'll need in JWT payload.
        return Users.findOneById(jwtPayload.id)
            .then(user => {
                return cb(null, user);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return cb(err);
            });
    }
));
```

Comment: why are you using a JWT as a secret when you sign a token? And why do you put the complete user object into the payload? Do you get any errors/exceptions?

Comment: no, not getting any error but not getting the token either